# Interrupt UrlConnection on back presss

Tags: android, android-asynctask, interrupt, urlconnection

In my Android Application I have two activities: Main and Articles. My application starts with Main. In Articles I am showing Images which are downloaded from server.

Here is the code to download the images from server:

```
public class SyncImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
private String url;
private URLConnection connection;

public SyncImage(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

@Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Bitmap img;
        try {
            URL source = new URL(url);
            connection = source.openConnection();
            Handler.addUrlConnection(connection);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.connect();
            img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
            return img;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Articles activity**

```
private void downloadImages(ArrayList<String> images) {
        for (String image : images) {
            SyncImage sync = new SyncImage(image);
            sync.execute();
            // Rest of the code
        }
    }
```

What I want that if user press back button to go back to Main Screen, all UrlConnection objects should cancel/stop their executions.

I can cancel the SyncImage object using sync.cancel(true), but it will only stop AsyncTask object, not the URLConnection object in process.

So, how to cancel the ongoing execution UrlConnection objects on Back Press?

Comment: You start a lot of asynctasks. But only one will be active as they run sequentially. So you can cancel all and there will be only one url connection left as the others are not established yet.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override

public void onBackPressed() {
    connection = null;
    url = "";
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `Connection` and `SyncImage` class variable and then try to disconnect connection as follows :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    connection.close();
    connection.disconnect();
    SyncImages.cancel(true);
    finish();
  }
```

Comment: Sorry but UrlConnection doesn't has any close or disconnect method.

Comment: You should use HttpUrlConnection instead of UrlConnection